# Handle an exception in a trigger in oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers

I'm a rookie in oracle and I want to display an error when (expAnnee*100 + expMois) < YYMM (YYMM of SYSDATE) to check the validity of a credit card.

expAnnee and expMois are numbers.

I get the following error:

```
PLS-00201: identifier 'NEW.EXPANNEE' must be declared
```

But this is a trigger, and in my "InfoCredit" table expAnnee and expMois are indeed there.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER VALID_CARD
BEFORE INSERT ON INFOCREDIT
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    ex_expired EXCEPTION;
    testdate NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT to_number(to_char(to_date(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'YYMM'))
    INTO testdate
    FROM Dual;

    if ((new.expAnnee*100+new.expMois) < testdate)
    Then RAISE ex_expired;
    END IF;

EXCEPTION

    WHEN ex_expired
    THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CARD EXPIRED');

END;
/
```

Comment: Provide your compilation error message.

Comment: PLS-00201: identifier 'NEW.EXPANNEE' must be declared

Comment: You have missed the semicolon in front of `NEW`.

Comment: I didn't know you needed those! Thanks! You're the best.!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to `new` as `:new`

E.g.

`if ((:new.expAnnee*100+:new.expMois) < testdate)`